# how can i confirm my user email to change user status

Tags: javascript, email, backend

I have been finding a way to confirm my user email.
is there any way to send to the user confirmation message and then he/she confirm email there.
then I get the request to change user information for instance if he confirms the email `user.status.verify_email = true`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a unique url associated with the user, and send that url directly to the user's unverified email. If that url is accessed, verify the associated user. You could try to implement this from scratch or use a library like [email-verification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-verification) on NPM.